# Is it possible to check what file tumblerd is currently looking at?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, thumbnails

I just cloned a big folder and tumblerd has started eating my CPU. I'm now curious about what particular file it is working on. Is there any way to see what file it is currently trying to make a thumbnail of?

Comment: You've not provided any release details; but I usually use `lsof` to list open files to explore where its *indexing*... though there are many different ways of course  (including `top` type ways to watch it change too, such as when I added an external drive, allowing me to scan the various folders of images which provide me a clue as to progress)

Comment: Use `sudo lsof -c tumblerd`. Read `man lsof`.